# Adding OnClick listener to the view in android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am developing an android application in which I want to achieve this:

[image]
The android layout xml code is given below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/track_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/track_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/track_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/track_image" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="#333333"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selected_track_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/play"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_track_title"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_control"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want that whenever user click on any of the area with in the whole view shown with image and text the audio gets play. But in my xml code I can only add image onClick listener. Every kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Make click for parent layout.

Comment: You can add click listener on root(RelativeLayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Assign id to the parent view i.e. RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**2.** Add click listener to relative layout

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {

        //handle click here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add onClick in layout that group all content witch should be clickable:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:onClick="clickMe"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```